# Is there any way to change the font color and size of labels in Chartjs 3.0.0

Tags: javascript, chart.js, chart.js3

Using the chart.js 3.0.0 beta

It appears they have not yet implemented any way to change the font properties of the labels (
Volume and Month in the self-contained sample below )

I try a couple of methods but it seems like this is just not possible

To be clear it is the labels I want to change the color of - not the title or the datasets.

can anyone confirm this?

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.0.0-beta.12/chart.js"></script>
 
</head>

<body>
    <div id="container" style='background-color:white' >
        <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
    </div>
 
    <script>
            
window.onload = function() {

    var ctx = document.getElementById('canvas').getContext('2d');

    var chart = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: 'bar',
        data: {
            labels: ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July'],
            datasets: [{            
                data: [     50,     -90,        75,     40,     -100,       220,        11      ]   
            }]
        },
        options: {
            indexAxis: 'y',
            plugins: {
                    legend: {
                        display: false,
                        labels:{
                            fontSize: 20,
                            fontColor: 'red',
                        }
                    },
                    title: {
                        display: true,
                        text: 'Chart.js Horizontal Bar Chart'
                    },
            },
            scales: {
                    x: {
                        display: true,
                        scaleLabel: {
                            display: true,
                            labelString: 'Volume',
                            fontColor:'#666',
                            fontSize: 20,
                            fontStyle: 'italic'
                        }
                    },
                    y: {
                        display: true,
                        scaleLabel: {
                            display: true,
                            labelString: 'Month',
                            fontColor:'#666',
                            fontSize: 20,
                            fontStyle: 'bold'
                        }
                    }
            }           
        }
    }); 
};
             
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The propertys have changed in naming in v3 see migration guide (https://www.chartjs.org/docs/master/getting-started/v3-migration) and the font docs (https://www.chartjs.org/docs/master/general/fonts) for more info:

Example:

```js
var options = {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"],
    datasets: [{
        label: '# of Votes',
        data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
        borderWidth: 1
      },
      {
        label: '# of Points',
        data: [7, 11, 5, 8, 3, 7],
        borderWidth: 1
      }
    ]
  },
  options: {
    plugins: {
      legend: {
        labels: {
          font: {
            size: 20
          },
          color: 'red',
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

var ctx = document.getElementById('chartJSContainer').getContext('2d');
new Chart(ctx, options);
```

```html
<body>
  <canvas id="chartJSContainer" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.0.0-beta.12/chart.js" integrity="sha512-KTkh8VBBRBzCXlXeR49sBgmLkU6CE7li47A70NR+yYMKGEDOfQR4L2PEQ3KRXeET8j1U+gSRpRjkAS4tQjTGag==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
```